Cocoapods Build Error for Using Inner/Nested Class from Another Pod
I have two custom pods, PodA and PodB, and I'm facing a build error when trying to use an inner/nested class from PodA in PodB. I want to create a BCustomView in PodB that subclasses CustomView from PodA. However, I get the error: 'Cannot find interface declaration for 'CustomView', superclass of 'BCustomView''.
Of course, I set the s.dependency 'PodA' in PodB.podspec.
Here is the code in PodA:
import UIKit

public enum PodA {}
extension PodA {
    open class CustomView:UIview {}
}

And Pod B:
import PodA

public class BCustomView : PodA.CustomView {}

The error occurs in BPod-Swift.h:
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC16PodBBCustomView")
@interface BCustomView : CustomView
- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)coder OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end

I also have PodC and PodD, which similarly use PodA in the same way, and I'm encountering inconsistent build results where some builds succeed while others fail. I wonder why It happens.
Is there any way to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for your help.
I have tried the following:

set s.dependency 'PodA' in PodB.podspec.
Clean Build Folder
pod update/reinstall
align development target (iOS versions)

